# Rotate a string in C

Tags: c, string

I am trying to shift a string both left and right given the number of positions to shift the string by.

This is what I wrote so far but it does not work.

```
void Shift(char* string, shift)
{
    int length = strlen(string)-1;
    int i;
    char *buff;
    buff = malloc((sizeof(char) *shift) + 1);
    strncpy(buff, string, shift);
    buff[shift] = '/0';
    while (string[i + shift] != '/0')
        string[i++] = string[i + shift];
    strcat(string, buff);
}
```

How can I fix this? 
This should be the example:
shift = 1

HELLO ->
OHELL

Comment: "does not work" is not a clear problem statement. Can you please edit your question with a more specific problem statement?

Comment: What's `n` in `buff[n] = '\0'` and what does it have to do with anything?

Comment: Fix your function signature. It is not standard.

Comment: Do not use `strncpy`.

Comment: It is called "rotation" of a string

Comment: @melpomene Why one should not use strncpy ?

Comment: don't forget to cleanup....

Comment: Yes, please edit the title and post to indicate you want to rotate a string.

Comment: @Ra'Jiska Because it is an abomination and should not exist. It has very non-obvious semantics and a misleading name, and the functionality it encapsulates is not something you should make use of in the first place.

Comment: What's `n` anyway? Looks like some ghost to me.

Comment: @Ra'Jiska Basically the only use for `strncpy` is to implement low-level file system code in System V Unix. It sucks for anything else.

Comment: it's the number of position to shift by

Comment: Really? Than what `shift` is?

Comment: @melpomene Well I'm not sure I agree with it all, but how would you copy the first 10 characters of a string into another one if not using `strncpy` ? What alternative do you have ?

Comment: im sorry, I just updated it. n is shift, my bad

Comment: @Ra'Jiska I'm confused because that's not what `strncpy` does. How would you do it with `strncpy`?

Comment: @Pino This is something that is not well tolerated here - You should post *the exact code* causing the troubles, not some kind of hypothetical "similar" code.

Comment: @melpomene "The  strncpy()  function is similar -- than strcpy --, except that at most n bytes of src are copied.  Warning: If there is no null byte among the first n  bytes of src, the string placed in dest will not be null-terminated." Basically, it copies from str A to str B with n bytes at most.

Comment: @Ra'Jiska In this case, an alternative to `strncpy` is `memcpy`.

Comment: @Ra'Jiska Yes, so show me how you would use it to copy the first 10 characters of a string into another string. What does the actual call look like?

Comment: @melpomene `strncpy(dest, src, 10);` Stnrcpy does the same work of `memcpy` except that `strncpy` would stop at the null byte.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: This thread is a disaster. The question is woefully incomplete: just a generic 'uh it doesnt work' without anything to build off, the comments are on a speeding train to somewhere completely different, and all the answers posted so far have dumped code without explaining what was wrong with the original.

Comment: @Ra'Jiska That is incorrect. `strncpy` always writes exactly `n` bytes. It does not stop writing at a null byte. It just stops reading at a null byte. But that's not what you said you wanted to happen anyway (copy a string *to a string*): If `src` is longer than 9 characters, `strncpy` won't write a null byte to `dest`, so `dest` ends up either being not a string (no termination) or containing garbage characters from the previous contents (if there's an existing null byte somewhere past index 9).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution rotates the string in place using O(1) storage:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void rotleftmem(void *p, size_t len, size_t lshift)
{
    unsigned char *d;
    size_t start;
    size_t dx, sx;
    size_t todo;
    unsigned char x;

    if (!len)
        return;
    lshift %= len;
    if (!lshift)
        return;

    d = p;
    todo = len;
    for (start = 0; todo; start++) {
        x = d[start];
        dx = start;
        while (1) {
            todo--;
            sx = dx + lshift;
            if (sx >= len || sx < dx /*overflow*/)
                sx -= len;
            if (sx == start) {
                d[dx] = x;
                break;
            }
            d[dx] = d[sx];
            dx = sx;
        }
    }
}

void *rotatemem(void *p, size_t len, ssize_t rshift)
{
    if (len) {
        size_t lshift = rshift < 0 ? -rshift : len - rshift % len;

        rotleftmem(p, len, lshift);
    }
    return p;
}

char *rotatestr(char *s, ssize_t rshift)
{
    return rotatemem(s, strlen(s), rshift);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ssize_t rshift;
    char *s;

    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "usage: %s N STR\n"
                "Rotate STR right by N or left by -N\n",
                argv[0]);
        return 2;
    }

    rshift = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    s = argv[2];
    printf("%s\n", rotatestr(s, rshift));
    return 0;
}
```

The guts of the code is in function `rotleftmem`, which rotates a block of memory of specified length left by a specified, unsigned "left-shift" value. `rotatemem` is a wrapper around `rotleftmem` that rotates in either direction; a negative shift value rotates left and a positive shift value rotates right; the signed shift value is converted to a positive "left-shift" value. `rotatestr` is a wrapper around `rotatemem` that takes a pointer to a null-terminated string instead of a pointer to void plus a length. Both `rotatestr` and `rotatemem` return the original pointer.

For `rotleftmem`, if the block length (`len`) is non-zero, the "left-shift" value (`lshift`) is reduced modulo `len`. If either of `len` or the  (reduced) `lshift` value is 0, the function does nothing. Otherwise, the outer loop will iterate `GCD(len, lshift)` times (where `GCD(a, b)` is the greatest common divisor of `a` and `b`). For each iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop will iterate `len / GCD(len, lshift)` times, so the total number of iterations of the inner loop is `len`. The time complexity is O(n), where n is the length of the block.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is modulo based, use negative number to shift on the left and positive numbers to shift on the right.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void shift(char* string, int shift)
{
    char *tmp = strdup(string);
    int len = strlen(string);
    if (shift < 0)
        shift = len + (shift % len);
    for (int i = 0; string[i] != 0; i++) {
        int new_idx = (i + shift) % len;
        tmp[new_idx] = string[i];
    }
    memcpy(string, tmp, len);
    free(tmp);
}

int main(void) {
    char test[] = "coucou";
    shift(test, -9);
    printf("%s\n", test);
    return 0;
}
```

The trick is to compute where each charachter is going to end up in the destination string. By using modulo of the total size you make sure it stays in between bounds, thus adding the offset and then ensuring it stays in bounds gives the correct index.

For the left shift, i just transformed the left shift offset into a right shift offset and re-used the right shifting code.

Answer (score 1):

you can use XOR bitwise operator to swap characters and loop to reverse them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void reverse(char *a, int n) {

  for (int i=0, j=n-1; i < j; i++, j--) {
      a[i] = a[i] ^ a[j];
      a[j] = a[j] ^ a[i];
      a[i] = a[i] ^ a[j];
  }
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

int k = 1; // shift count
int n = 5;
char a[] = "HELLO";

reverse(&a[n-k], k); // reverse end of array
reverse(a, n-k);     // reverse beginning of array
reverse(a, n);       // reverse entire array

// print output
for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%c\n", a[i]);
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: `a[i] ^= a[j] ^= a[i] ^= a[j];` has undefined behavior. It needs a sequence point between each assignment.

Comment: @IanAbbott I went ahead and expanded it. order of operations should be defined now.

Comment: The three-xor swap thing is an anti-pattern. It does too many memory writes and creates a false dependency that interferes with pipelining. Just use a temporary; registers are plentiful these days, so you might as well use one. If you want to speed up reverse, use SIMD instructions to reverse 16 bytes at a time (8 bytes from each end) or even more on recent CPUs.